# Get first and last value from groups using rle

Tags: r

I want to get first and last value for groups using grouping similar to what rle() function does.

For example I have this data frame:

```
> df
   df time
1   1    A
2   1    B
3   1    C
4   1    D
5   2    E
6   2    F
7   2    G
8   1    H
9   1    I
10  1    J
11  3    K
12  3    L
13  3    M
14  2    N
15  2    O
16  2    P
```

I want to get something like this:

```
> want
  df first last
1  1     A    D
2  2     E    G
3  1     H    J
4  3     K    M
5  2     N    P
```

How you can see, I want to group my values in a way rle() function does. I want to group elements only when this same value is next to each other. group_by groups elements in the different way.

```
> rle(df$df)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 4 3 3 3 3
  values : num [1:5] 1 2 1 3 2
```

Is there a solution for my problem? Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function `rleid` from `data.table` that does that job, i.e.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)[, .(df = head(df, 1), 
              first = head(time, 1), 
              last = tail(time, 1)), 
      by = (grp = rleid(df))][, grp := NULL][]
```

Which gives,

> ```
>    df first last
> 1:  1     A    D
> 2:  2     E    G
> 3:  1     H    J
> 4:  3     K    M
> 5:  2     N    P
> ```

Adding a `dplyr` approach, as @RonakShah mentions

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(grp = cumsum(c(0, diff(df)) != 0)) %>% 
 summarise(df = first(df), 
           first = first(time), 
           last = last(time)) %>% 
 select(-grp)
```

Giving,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 3
>      df first  last
>   <int> <chr> <chr>
> 1     1     A     D
> 2     2     E     G
> 3     1     H     J
> 4     3     K     M
> 5     2     N     P
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @RonakShah if you're using `dplyr`, might as well do `first = first(time), last = last(time)`. Nice and clear.

Comment: Second approach gives me an error : Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'grp' not found. Do you know why?

Comment: It's the `group_by` that gives the problem. Maybe try naming `df` variable to something else as `df` is also the name of the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `base R` with `rle`.  Once we do the `rle` on the first column, replicate the sequence of `values` with `lengths`, use that to create logical index with `duplicated`, then subset the values of the original dataset based on the index

```
rl <- rle(df[,1])
i1 <- rep(seq_along(rl$values), rl$lengths)
i2 <- !duplicated(i1)
i3 <- !duplicated(i1, fromLast = TRUE)
wanted <- data.frame(df = df[i2,1], first =  df[i2,2], last = df[i3,2])
wanted
#   df first last
#1  1     A    D
#2  2     E    G
#3  1     H    J
#4  3     K    M
#5  2     N    P
```